# java- how to print repetitive numbers of array inside "()"

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wanted to print an array with repetitive numbers inside parenteses, any idea of how?

array:

```
{2,4,5,5,5,7,1,1,4}
```

I need to print it as:

```
24(555)7(11)4
```

Here's my pseudocode:

```
boolean inRun = false;
 for loop;
 if (inRun); 
if values[i] != the preceding value, print ")"; 
inRun = false; 
if(!inRun) 
if values[i] = the following value, print "("
 inRun = true; 
System.out.print([i]) 
if inRun, print ")"
```

Comment: Is the output format fixed for any given set of input numbers?

Comment: We are not here to do your (home)work for you entirely, but we are here to help you figure out problems you're stuck on. Post any code you've tried so far. Show that you've made some effort.

Comment: Hi, I have my pseudocode: boolean inRun = false; for loop; if (inRun); if values[i] != the preceding value, print ")"; inRun = false; if(!inRun) if values[i] = the following value, print "(" inrun = true; System.out.print([i]) if inRun, print ")"

Comment: http://www.ideone.com/sKOvw is the working solution

Comment: http://www.ideone.com/xdH9H is the new solution.

Comment: @learnerNo1,Please accept anubhavas solution and upvote for him.

Comment: @learnerNo1,Please accept anubhavas solution and upvote for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){


        int arr[] = new int[5];
        arr[0] = 5;
        arr[1] = 3;
        arr[2] = 2;

        arr[3] = 2;

        arr[4] = 3;


        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.print("(" + arr[0]);
        for (int i=1; i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i] == arr[i-1]) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(")(" + arr[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.print(")");
    }
}
```

output : (22)(33)(5)